# Cannot write mongo db logs to syslog

Tags: mongodb, ubuntu, logging, syslog, rsyslog

I wish to redirect the mongodb.log to syslog. Any help will be useful?

I used the 
systemLog:
destination: syslog
systemFacility: mongodb

in mongodb.conf and tried restarting mongo db. But it does not writes anything to syslog.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

while starting your mongo service you can define the log path with 'logpath' i.e.

```
mongod --logpath /path/.../name.log
```

Comment: Thanks mehta but my requirement is to write the logs to /var/log/syslog instead of a .log file

Comment: Both. But logpath replaces syslog and syslog service cannot write to it. So i opted for systemlogpath.destination: syslog in mongod.conf

Comment: Vote my question :D

Comment: if you can favorite my question too. i can get some reputation